# Ho to download Data in Bulk from Moodle, such as course completion and user data?

Tags: download, moodle

I would like to download Data, from Moodle site. I am trying to download in bulk, course completion, and all the info with regards to the users? I am looking at adding this sate to a database for analysis on an excel document.
Any support will be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you just try something and then ask when facing problems. We are not free of cost developers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have course completion switched on, there is a report for the course.

If you go to a course page, then on the course administration menu go to reports -> course completion, it will display a list of enrolled users with their completion status - there is also an option to download a csv file.

I would suggest taking a look at the code in `/report/completion/index.php?course=xx`